# How to make stack containing retained S3 bucket redeployable?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I've created a CDK stack with a bucket which has a fixed name, using `bucketName: [omitted]`. The bucket is retained, using `removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN`. I've also run `overrideLogicalId` for the bucket to set its logical ID to a fixed string.

Now, if I `cdk destroy && cdk deploy`, the `destroy` command runs fine, and the bucket is retained. But the `deploy` command fails with the following error (bucket name and ID anonymized):

> MyStack | 2:53:21 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::Bucket    | MyUniqueBucketName (uniqueBucketName123456789012) unique-bucket-name-123456789012 already exists

What else do I need to do to avoid having to juggle buckets manually when redeploying a stack from scratch?

Comment: Why not follow CDK [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names) and avoid the fixed bucket name?

Comment: @fedonev It's an explicit goal (and not an unreasonable one, IMO) to have human-readable bucket names.

Comment: There isn't a neat way to achieve this because this goes against the AWS-prescribed practice of having your CDK app be deterministic (synth to the same template regardless of already-deployed resources). You may work around this using an synth-time SDK call, but you should be aware that this goes against CDK best practices and will likely result in some pain down the line (your IaC will not be the source of truth anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to destroy/redeploy a stack's resources, while retaining the same bucket across deploys.  Consider refactoring to a two-stack app that deploys stateful and stateless resources separately.  This solves the problem simply and in conformity with CDK [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html).<sup>1</sup>

Move your S3 bucket into a Stateful Stack.  The bucket's stack deploys once and is never destroyed.<sup>2</sup>  The Stateful Stack class exposes the `s3.Bucket` as an attribute, which you pass as a prop to Stateless Stack.  Put your disposable resources in Stateless Stack.  It references the bucket via its props.  Stateless Stack can now be destroyed/deployed repeatedly without breaking the app's references.

Here are the CLI commands.  I omit the `--app` flag, is assumed to be in `cdk.json`.  List the app's stacks:

```
cdk ls

MyStatefulStack
MyStatelessStack
```

Deploy both stacks as a one-time step (or if your stateful resources change):

```
cdk deploy --all
```

From now on, deploy and destroy only `MyStatelessStack`.  It never loses the reference it has to the CLoudFormation `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource created by Stateful Stack.

```
cdk destroy MyStatelessStack

cdk deploy MyStatelessStack
```

As an added bonus, the [Stateful/Stateless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-separate) pattern allows for extra security against accidental deletion of Stateful Stack, like stack termination protection or applying restrictive IAM deletion permissions.

---

1. My first instinct was to solve this problem with a SDK call (does the bucket exist in S3?) and conditional logic to  handle cases where the bucket does or does not.  Sometimes a SDK command is the least bad option.  Upon reflection, though, I think the Stateful/Stateless pattern is a better fit.  See the [Avoid non-deterministic deploys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context) best practice docs for considerations when adding SDK calls to CDK apps.
2. Because the bucket resource is never destroyed, its `RemovalPolicy.RETAIN` setting isn't strictly necessary, but is still a good idea.